# Php file just displays number 1?

Tags: php

So I got an Steam Market Price API, but if I go to it through my PHP file it will display "1". example: cost.php?name=blablabla

```
<?php
if (isset($params,$item)){
$params['format'] = 'json';
$params['data'] =json_encode($package_data);
$item = $_GET['item'];
$item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
$item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
$item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
$item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);
@include_once ("set.php");
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name='$item'");
$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=".$item;
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
    if(time()-$row["lastupdate"] < 3600) die($row["cost"]);
}
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($params));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$results = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($results);
if($results->{'success'} == "0") die("notfound");{
$lowest_price = $results->{'median_price'};
$lowest_price[strlen($lowest_price)] = 0;
$lowest_price = str_replace("$","",$lowest_price);
$lowest_price = floatval($lowest_price);
}
mysql_query("DELETE FROM items WHERE name='$item'");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO items (`name`,`cost`,`lastupdate`) VALUES ('$item','$lowest_price','".time()."')");
print_r($results);  
}
?>
```

My question would be is there someone who know an solution for that one?

Comment: Try accessing that link via browser and see what you get if you get propper json string then it could be the headers returned by API. Normally I would not use file_get_contents for an API as it could have some speciffic headers set that may not allow it to be read as a file. Tru using cURL functionality to connect to API.

Comment: Hey, I just tried curl. Now it's just an white page

Comment: well curl by itself does not give you any output. Set the curl settings, make the request, get the results object and display results from that. http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php cURL may be a bit overwhelming at first if you never used it before, but after some practice it becomes quite simple.

Comment: I updated my code again, not it doesn't show me an "1", but shows me error on line 29

Comment: edit your question and point out which one is line 29

Comment: I've edited my comment

Comment: `(floatval)` does not exist in php. it's just `(float)`. or maybe you mean `floatval($var)`, which DOES exist.

Comment: Thanks, but now I see again that "1" btw. I got also 2nd code what is a lot different than that, but it works. Can someone help me fixing that code so it shows that what "API" shows?

Comment: do a `var_dump($results)` right after this line `$results = json_decode($result, true);` and update your question with the output.

Comment: I've updated my code again, now it's just blank website

Comment: add this line at the top of your file `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and try again

Comment: Still Blank Page, with error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: What do your PHP log files say?

Comment: Nothing, Anyone got any fixes?

Comment: join [this chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100781/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-34809934-php-file-just-displays-number-1) to talk more

Comment: Hey, we should think out something like. If it didn't work then I do something and if it did, then I do something, so I don't have to type here everytime. Btw that didn't work out

Comment: Can you make a chat on some other website maybe? So I can talk as well :D

Comment: @TõnisKivimägi which log files did you look in?

Comment: I looked in php - logs - error_logs

Comment: Alex Andrei You can help me out please :)?

Answer (score 0):

`$lowest_price` is an `array`

```
$lowest_price = $obj->{'lowest_price'};
$lowest_price[strlen($lowest_price)] = 0; // <-- here you are making it into an array
$lowest_price = str_replace("$","",$lowest_price);
$lowest_price = floatval($lowest_price);
```

You are casting an to `float` so basically the process is working fine.

See how `floatval` behaves http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php#refsect1-function.floatval-returnvalues

You should cast the values of the array or just enable `error_reporting` to catch all the notices.

Comment: I updated my code again, not it doesn't show me an "1", but shows me error on line 29